# Is it possible to go to next/prev reference while the references list are shown in the sidebar and not in the peek window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I personally don't like the peek window, so I have that disabled. `Find all References` command finds and displays them nicely in the sidebar, but I cannot go back and forth between them.
None of the following commands actually go to the next reference while the "References" sidebar is open:

`references-view.next`

`goToNextReference`

`goToNextReferenceFromEmbeddedEditor` (being desperate here)

ps: from peek it works

Comment: `references-view.next` works for me.  Run the `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` command and is what your keybinding for `references-view.next` is being resolved to.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I got it working.